# How can I schedule comments in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have an question - how can I schedule comments in WordPress?
I searched through results in Google and I didn't find anything. Maybe some function exist?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be about programming at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following settings to schedule post

1. When you are ready to schedule your post or page, click on Document
   Settings in the sidebar of the post or page Editor.
2. Under Status & Visibility, click the hyperlinked Immediately next to
   Publish.
3. Select the date and time you want the post or page to publish.
4. Click Schedule to schedule your post or page.